# Save just the relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to persist just a relationship in Neo4j but doesn't work. See my query. My domain object has this relationship to itself.

```
@RelatedTo (type="PLUS_ME", direction = Direction.BOTH)
private Set<Errand> plusMe;
```

Then I run this query with a GraphRepository.

```
    Errand e = new Errand ();
    Errand e1 = new Errand ();
    e = template.save(e);
    e1 = template.save(e1);
    p (e.getId() + " " + e1.getId ());
    String query = "MATCH (one:Errand)" +
               "WHERE one.id = " + e.getId() +
               "MATCH (two:Errand)" +
               "WHERE two.id = " + e1.getId() +
               "CREATE (one)-[b:PLUS_ME]->(two)" +
               "CREATE (two)-[a:PLUS_ME]->(one)";
    eRepo.query(query, null);
```

But when I run this query with junit I get 0 as the size that is.

```
    eRepo.findByPlusMe(e).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use parameters
2. you don't need the inverse relationship
3. are you sure your match statements returns the correct errands?
4. can you show the structure of your `Errand` class?
5. is your findByPlusMe repository query a annotated or derived query?